# How to commit local changes from master to another branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to working with Git and a few things or commands are clear to me. My problem now is described here:

Yesterday I got the latest version of `master`. I have made some local changes, which in the end were more than expected. Now I want to commit this local status to another `branch` (which is named *"image_acquisition"*).

So my questions in summary are:

1. I am "2 commits behind master". What do I have to take into account so that I do not break anything? Is this step even necessary?
2. More important: how should the command be so I get everything clean on the branch?

I'm just scared to lose all my changes in case I do something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *haven't* yet committed your local work, then I suggest that do a `git stash` to stash away your current working directory and stage.  Then, create a new branch from `master` and apply your stash.  Try this:

```
# from master
git stash
git checkout -b your_feature
git stash apply
git commit -m 'completed a feature'
```

This would leave you on a new branch `your_feature`, with a single commit containing all your work.  What you would do from this point would depend on your workflow.  A typical next step would be to push your branch to the remote, and create a pull request:

```
git push origin your_feature
# then create pull request on GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.
```

If you *have* already made one or more commits, then the situation is a bit more complicated.  In this case, you might just commit your local work, and then create a new branch:

```
# from master
git commit -m 'completed a feature'
git branch your_feature
```

Then, you may rollback `master` to before you made the commits.  For example, if you have already made three commits, including the one above, then you could try:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Now, you have a bona fide feature branch with three commits, and `master` should be behind the remote, and it should not be ahead of the remote.

Comment: I implemented the first variant (no commits have been made so far), everything worked smoothly. Thank you for the detailed and elegant answer and solution. Have a nice day.